# Knockout Multiple View Models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a page where i have a Editable View through form elements, they are observables on key-down, the View is connected to two live preview on the same page.

When i initially apply bindings with sample data, all three areas - the form, two live preview areas get loaded up with sample data

```
<div id="create">
<!--Contains form elements-->
<form>
<!--Data Should not load during inital page load, empty textboxes should be shown to user. When user clicks on this text box, This values should be connected to two previews, replacing the sample data already binded
--> <input type="text" data-bind="value: jw_fullname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="Full Name" id="jw_fullname" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="preview1">
Template One
<h1 id="title" data-bind="text: jw_fullname">
Sample data loaded here during page load
</h1>
</div>

<div id="preview2">
Template two
<p data-bind="text: jw_fullname"></p>
Sample data loaded here during page load
</div>
```

But i require only two previews to be loaded with sample data, Not the form elements, The elements should be empty during initial binding, when user clicks on the form element first name, whatever the user types in should be binded to both preview's replacing the sample data that is already loaded.

I am trying with

```
  ko.applyBindings(my.vm.sample, document.getElementById('preview1'));
    ko.applyBindings(my.vm.sample, document.getElementById('preview2'));
    ko.applyBindings(my.vm.emptydataset, document.getElementById('create'));
```

But i can't connect those, How to connect the user input to reflect in both previews?

However when i just use

```
ko.applyBindings(my.vm)
```

All three are in sync with each other, they work right. But i don't want the user to delete the sample data on the form.

Comment: Short answer: use one view model and bind it to a root object (you'll just end up fighting KO otherwise, although there are some more advanced use-cases). If some elements should not be shown, use an applicable binding to hide (or not create) the elements.

Comment: Form elements should be shown, but i don't want values to be loaded only on initial binding

Comment: Then bind it to some "empty" model data/observables first. You can either update the bound observables directly or use an observable of the data to bind (so the entire submodel can be replaced at once). I recommend looking at the `withProperties` binding shown in the KO custom binding documentation.

Comment: (See my recommendation about using an observable to wrap the submodel.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: jw_fullname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', emptyInit: emptyInit" placeholder="Full Name" id="jw_fullname" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.emptyInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                   viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        element.value = '';
    }
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.jw_fullname = ko.observable("A");
    this.emptyInit = ko.observable(true);
};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36ZCx/) of it

Comment: This solution is very simple. But one of the form element is a text area that already uses a custom binding handler for it's wysiwyg editor. If i use emptyInit with the text area, i get reference error : emptyInit not defined.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jpo/5540893 The custom binding for text area is cleditor can be found on the above gist

Comment: you need to modify your custom binding to assing an empty value at the element on init

Comment: regarding the `emptyInit` reference error you also need to add it in the viewmodel like in the example.

Comment: I have a problem with empty init, Initially it loads the empty form, that is well and good. But when user makes changes and sort the form elements (Knockout sortable), the updated value disappears again. I want empty form boxes only on intial load, if user changes the value and then sorts the form elements, the most recent value should display instead of empty text box, How to achieve this?

Comment: I suspect there is a conflict with the sortable. you can try and provide an update callback to the custom binding and see if it works. otherwise open a new question with a fiddle to have a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901833/knockout-initializing-empty-form-inputs-not-work-inside-sortable-elements