# Knockout initializing empty form inputs not work after sorting sortable form elements

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

Here is fiddle jsfiddle.net/jw7Je

I have a view model bounded to a two templates and an editable form in a single page.

The two templates are initially loaded with sample data, The form is displayed without sample data through this custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.emptyInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                   viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        element.value = '';
    }
}

<input type="text" data-bind="value: jw_fullname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', emptyInit: emptyInit" placeholder="Full Name" id="jw_fullname" />
```

Everything loads up fine initially, but the i have sortable sections of forms through knockout sortable.

```
<div data-bind="sortable: data"> 
<div class="item">
       <p class="span6">
       <label>Course Name</label>
       <input type="text" data-bind="valueWithInit: jw_educname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',emptyInit: jw_educname" placeholder="Course Name" class="educname" />
       </p>
       <p class="span6">
       <label>Institution Name</label>
       <input type="text" data-bind="value: jw_eduiname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', emptyInit: jw_eduiname" placeholder="Insitution Name" class="eduiname" />
       </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the user make the change to the form and sorts the elements, the corresponding elements values resets to empty again, although the values in the view model are updated.

How to retain the updated values in those textboxes in sortable sections ?

I am trying with

```
ko.bindingHandlers.emptyInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                   viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {

            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || '';

            if (element.value !== value) {
                element.value = value;

            }else {
                element.value = '';
            }

    },
     update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                   viewModel, bindingContext) 
     {
              var value = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
            //console.log(valueUnwrapped);



     }
}
```

Comment: consider providing a fiddle demonstrating this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields get cleared because Knockout-sortable removes the moved elements and adds new ones in their place.

I found this pull request that seems to solve the problem: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/pull/83

Comment: I face other issue http://jsfiddle.net/jw7Je/3/ one of the form element is textarea that is custom binded to cleditor, after sorting the value disappears in cleditor alone, However this doesn't happen in my previous version of code.

Comment: when using knockout sortable 0.8.6 'cleditor' custom binding works fine but sortable removes sections, but in your version of knockout sortable the sections are moved instead of recreating but cleditor custom binding fails, can you please make both to work under single file? or can you kindly point out lines to be changed in most recent version of knockout sortable?

Comment: That problem appears to be an issue between the jQuery-UI sortable code and CLEditor. If I switch back to the original Knockout-sortable (http://jsfiddle.net/jw7Je/4/), I can still break the editor by starting to drag a section, but putting it back in the original spot. In that case, Knockout-sortable doesn't do any re-rendering. In other words, it only works when swapping places because Knockout-sortable re-renders it.

Comment: The cleditor doesn't break in your fiddle even when sorting or putting back in original place.  http://jsfiddle.net/jw7Je/5/ 
If you think if its an issue with jQuery UI & cleditor, How can i take this forward to fix? Should i do something in cleditor custom binding? or editor source js? I also see no errors or warning in console.

Comment: To see what I mean you need to drag a section and drop it in the same spot.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are referring to. How do you think i take this forward to fix? i posted a seperate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925441/knockout-custom-binding-cleditor-fails-after-sorting-elements-through-knockout-s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48024/discussion-between-jagan-k-and-michael-best)

Comment: Regardless, you should accept my answer since it answers the question you posted.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I accepted that as an answer. I found this discussion, that very exactly replicate my problem 
groups.google.com/forum/… 

however i couldn't able to use it in custom binding handler, i get refresh not a function error. Could you please spend your 5 mins, I hope you could fix this for sure. Thank You