# Custom binding for cleditor fails after sorting elements through knockout sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-sortable, cleditor

First up: check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw7Je/6/).

I have sortable array of elements created with the Knockout sortable library. When I initially apply the binding the cleditor initializes fine.

However, when sortable elements are sorted, the cleditor fails to re-initialize (I'm not sure what happens but cleditor fails). The cleditor just displays "true" instead of actual value in Firefox, and nothing in all other browsers.

I'm trying to figure out where the problem is, whether it is on the custom binding, or jQuery-UI, or the Knockout sortable library?

I am not recieving any errors in my console.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.cleditor = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var modelValue = valueAccessor(),
                allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

            var $editor = jQuery(element).cleditor({
                height: 50,
                controls: "bold italic underline | bullets numbering | undo redo"
            });

            $editor[0].change(function() {

                var elementValue = $editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML;
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                    modelValue(elementValue);

                } else {
                    if (allBindings['_ko_property_writers'] && allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].cleditor) {
                        allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].cleditor(elementValue);
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || '',
                $editor = jQuery(element).cleditor();

            if ($editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML !== value) {
                //$editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML = value;
                $editor[0].doc.body.innerHTML = value;
                $editor[0].focus();
            }
        }
    };
```

How can I make the cleditor to work, even after the elements are sorted?

I found [this resource](https://code.google.com/p/cleditor/issues/detail?id=24), but I couldn't find anything wrong in code as said in that topic.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cleditor/6W36CyPsaVU
I found this discussion exactly replicate the issue i have, but i couldn't use it because i get refresh() is not a function error. I use 1.4.4 cleditor version.

Comment: I put together this example to show that it has nothing to do with Knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/rh8c2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provided was helpful. The CLEditor `refresh` method is the right way to update it after it's dragged. It just needs to be done at the correct time, using the sortable `stop` event.

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).find("textarea").cleditor()[0].refresh();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/rh8c2/1/

I also worked to integrate this into your `cleditor` binding. In the `init` function:

```
jQuery(document).on('sortstop', function(event, ui) {
    if (jQuery.contains(ui.item[0], element)) {
        jQuery(element).cleditor()[0].refresh();
    }
});
```

I also made a change in the `update` function to keep the `<textarea>` value in sync, because `refresh` updates the editor's value from the `<textarea>`:

```
$editor[0].updateTextArea();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/jw7Je/7/

Comment: A million Thanks, I had been scratching my head to fix this for more than 24 hours. However i guessed that it should be on cleditor side.